# How to create a custom keyboard shortcut to center window in screen and resize to specific size

Tags: window-management, window-manager, window-decoration

Is there a way to create a custom keyboard shortcut that **centers** the current / selected window on the screen?

Is there a way to create a custom keyboard shortcut that **resizes** the current / selected window to a previously defined specific size?

In Windows 10, I use a small utility named "Sizer" by BrianApps (http://www.brianapps.net/sizer4/), which allows to accurately resize and reposition windows and I have grown very accustomed to it. Now, I am looking for a way to achieve this in elementary OS. Is there any **additional software** I could use for this same purpose?

[image: Sizer Configuration Menu]

[image: Sizer Entry Custom Size and Position]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the requested functionality using `wmctrl`. For example, the following command moves the active window to position X:400, Y:300, and resizes it to 800x500 px.

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,400,300,800,500
```

To bind it to a key, just go to Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts and create a custom shortcut with the command.

Check the [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) for more info about `wmctrl`.